# Lotka Volterra predator prey system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am doing a project work mainly saying the relation between jacobian matrix and lotka volterra predator prey method , and I had a doubt,when I find eigenvalues of the system,I got purely imaginary values.what did it mean and how can I conclude my project

Comment: Which Predator-Prey Model are you using?

Comment: iam using a cheetah and an antelope, is that what you asked

Answer (score 7):

If we use the Predator Prey Model:

$$x' = a x - \alpha x y \\ y' = - b y + \beta x y$$

where $a, b, \alpha, \beta$ are positive constants, we start by finding the critical points. The critical points are:

$$(0, 0), \left( \dfrac{b}{\beta}, \dfrac{a}{\alpha} \right)$$

The Jacobian matrix is given by:

$$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} a - \alpha y & -\alpha x\\ \beta y & -b + \beta x\end{bmatrix}$$

At $(0,0)$, we have:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & -b \end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $a$ and $-b$, hence an unstable saddle point.

At $\left( \dfrac{b}{\beta}, \dfrac{a}{\alpha} \right)$, we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\dfrac{\alpha b}{\beta} \\ \dfrac{a \beta}{\alpha} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\pm~ i~ \sqrt{ a b}$, which is a stable center.

A sample system and phase portrait showing this is:

[image]

To see both critical points (saddle and center), we have:

[image]

We would not care about starting with a population of $(0,0)$, the saddle, or negative populations, so we do not show that.

If we take any initial population of cheetahs and an antelopes, and follow the phase portrait, we see one species starting to dominate, but then the prey decreases, so the predators decrease and we are in a state of equilibrium (where one is not annihilating the other).

Comment: thankyou . what did it mean by unstable saddle point, and how can i say practicaly that initial critical point is unstable

Comment: @user100749: I added more details regarding the saddle and what you are looking with the stable center. If answers are helpful, you should upvote and/or accept them. Regards

Comment: thank you , i got the currect answer

Comment: if you dont mind may i ask you one more doubt.,

Comment: Nice work, portraits, and explanation! +1

Comment: can anybody explain the first graph

Comment: One axis represent the predators and the other the prey. Pick a starting point on a graph (the initial number of x and y). As you follow the trajectory, the number of predators increases, so the prey decreases, but then there is not enough prey, so the predators start to die off. This gives the prey time to recoup and the then the cycle starts over. This allows both to survive. Clear?

Comment: can you tell me more about the eigen value,and how can we say imaginery value of it imply a stable centre

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/srikrish/math251/notes/complexeigs.pdf and http://immune.math.yorku.ca/jmheffer/sites/default/files/topost_phaseplanehandout.pdf

Comment: When answers are helpful, you should upvote and/or accept them. You are welcome. Regards