# Eigenvector for non-linear predator-prey equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

I am currently working on a small project which involves mathematical biology.
It's been a while since I've visited Linear Algebra so any recollection would be helpful.

Consider the Predator-Prey equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt}\equiv \dot{x}\left ( t \right )=\alpha x-\beta x y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}\equiv  \dot{y}\left ( t \right )=\delta x y- \gamma y$

In this case, my physical constraints are

1) The predator do not die nor reproduce so their populations are constant with time

2) Standard assumption holds for Prey via the Predator-Prey model

Solving gives

$x\left ( t \right )=C_{2}e^{t\left ( \alpha-\beta C_{1} \right )}$

$y\left ( t \right )=C_{1}$

In matrix form:

$F=\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\ 
\dot{y}
\end{bmatrix}$

## =$\begin{bmatrix}
f_{1}\left ( x,y \right )\\ 
f_{2}\left ( x,y \right )
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha x -\beta x y\\ 
\delta x y-\alpha y
\end{bmatrix}$

The fixed points are $\left ( 0,0 \right )$ and $\left ( \frac{\gamma}{\delta } ,\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right )$.

But note that the system of equations are coupled so expressing them in matrix form may be impossible.

I'm thinking of taking the Jacobian 
J=
$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha -\beta y &\beta x \\ 
\delta y & \delta x-\gamma 
\end{bmatrix}$

in the eigenvector equation $J\vec{v}=\lambda \vec{v}$ to determine the eigenvectors.

My second strategy is to ignore the non-linear terms and solve the differential equation.It would also enable me to express the system of equation sans the non-linear terms as a matrix/ vector.

Am I justified in doing so?

Comment: You can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533211/lotka-volterra-predator-prey-system), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141289/lotka-volterra-first-integral-and-fixed-point), or perhaps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709845/lyapunov-function-for-predator-prey-system).

Comment: The second comment in the first link got me laughing real hard.@user539887

Comment: If the predator population is constant in time then you only have a single equation and there is no matrix system to look at. If you allow the predator population to change then you can linearise your system around fixed points, look at the Jacobian etc.

Comment: @Mathematicing: As that first linked, you only need to look at the signs of the eigenvalues and then practice care with the marginal cases. Are you being asked to find the eigenvectors, which is possible, but not really necessary?

Comment: @Moo I would like to determine the manifold which requires me to find the eigenvectors. How should the eigenvectors be found?

Comment: @David In this case then it suffice for me to plot $x(t) =....$ after solving the ODE and $y(t)=C_{1}$, right?

Comment: @David I'm actually confused at this point.
Since my assumption is that the predator number density is constant, I can solve the ODE and determine $y(t)$ and also for $x(t)$ easily. 
But if I then attempt to determine the eigenvalues from the two 2-tuple fixed points, I am unable to substitute them back into the expression for x(t) and y(t) since they do not have an eigenvalue component.

Comment: @Mathematicing: The two eigenvalues were shown in the first linked posting. We can find the eigenvectors by evaluating the RREF of $[A - \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$. For the first critical point $(0, 0)$, we have eigenvectors $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$. For the second critical point, we have eigenvectors $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\dfrac{i \sqrt{b}~ \alpha }{\sqrt{a} ~\beta } & 1 \\
 \dfrac{i \sqrt{b} ~\alpha }{\sqrt{a} ~\beta } & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Comment: @Mathematicing If the predator number is constant then $y(t)=C$, and you don't have a 2D system and this linearised analysis is not applicable.  I don't think you understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @David you are right. I was so steeped in a 2D diagram that I didn't realise the system of 2 equation is now just one equation.